# windows powershell check file-exist doesn't work

Tags: powershell

guys

i am learning PowerShell and I found its behaviour really strange. Basically, i cannot get any example script (from internet) working.

for instance, this one:

```
$WantFile = "C:\Users\psuser\Documents\GitHub\test\Bin\test.exe" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile 
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {Write-Host "Yippee"}
Else {Write-Host "No file at this location"}
```

looks pretty simply from a bash perspective, but i was told:

```
C:\Users\psuser\Documents\GitHub\test>$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
'$FileExists' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
-eq was unexpected at this time.
```

can anyone quickly let me know where i got it wrong?

thanks!

Comment: PowerShell commands only work when being called from with a PowerShell session

Answer (score 0):

You must run this command from within Powershell.

From CMD do

```
powershell -command "&{Test-Path 'C:\Users\psuser\Documents\GitHub\test\Bin\test.exe'}"
```